# Preserving MP4 quality when using VideoWriter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, computer-vision, mp4, video-processing

I'm loading a video file (mp4) to MATLAB using VideoReader and making some edits. When done, I'm trying to write (using VideoWriter) an mp4 file, however I lose quality (in spite of changing quality to 100).
I tried exporting as AVI and converting with ffmpeg, but ideally I would like to skip that part and get an extract directly from MATLAB.

Any ideas how to preserve that quality?

Comment: Why are you asking this again (and again without going into details!)? [Your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738910/mpeg4-quality-saved-in-matlab)

Comment: Asking this again since it was not answered yet, as you could probably see since you marked as duplicate.
Also, what details do you want?

Comment: Please read the rules. (And there was an answer, but never a reaction from your side what's wrong with it.)